# ¿Como obtener el valor de un campo en dialogo de TinyMCE 4?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Ya estuve revisando las respuestas de la pregunta [Get input field value from dialog box in TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156221/get-input-field-value-from-dialog-box-in-tinymce) pero no encontre solución a lo que busco.

Estoy haciendo un plugin para TinyMce donde se selecciona un `Type` y se ingresa un `Id` para poder crear un elemento html en el `content` del editor. Sin embargo no estoy pudiendo obtener el valor de estos campos.

[image: TinyMceCustomPlugin]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
var _dialogForm = {
    title: 'Exercise',
    body: [{
        type: 'form',
        layout: 'flex',
        direction: 'column',
        padding: 0,
        items: [
            {
                type: 'listbox',
                name: 'type',
                label: 'Type',
                value: 'internal',
                values: [
                    {
                        text: 'Internal exercise',
                        value: 'internal',
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'External exercise',
                        value: 'external',
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                type: 'textbox',
                name: 'id',
                label: 'Id',
                value: 'Internal'
            },
        ]
    }],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Insert',
            classes: 'btn primary',
            onclick: function (event) {

                // Asi pienso que se deberian de obtener

                const id = event.data.id;
                const type = event.data.type;

                console.log('id', event.data.id);
                console.log('type', event.data.type);

                editor.insertContent(`&nbsp;<exercise id="${type}" type="${type}" contenteditable="false">${_('Internal exercise')}</exercise>`);

                top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onclick: 'close',
        }
    ]
}

editor.windowManager.open(_dialogForm);
```

¿Como puedo obtener el valor de los campos?

```
{
    text: 'Insert',
    classes: 'btn primary',
    onclick: function (event) {

        // Asi pienso que se deberian de obtener

        const id = event.data.id;
        const type = event.data.type;

        console.log('id', event.data.id);
        console.log('type', event.data.type);

        editor.insertContent(`&nbsp;<exercise id="${type}" type="${type}" contenteditable="false">${_('Internal exercise')}</exercise>`);

        top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución para obtener los valores ingresados en el `customDialog`, estos se obtienen como parametro en la función `onSubmit`.

```
onSubmit: function(e) {
    console.log(`type: ${e.data.type}; id: ${e.data.id}`);
    editor.insertContent(`&nbsp;<p>Type: ${e.data.type}</p>`);
    editor.insertContent(`&nbsp;<p>Id: ${e.data.id}</p>`);
}
```

Este es el código:

```
editor.windowManager.open({
    title: 'Exercise',
    body: [{
        type: 'form',
        layout: 'flex',
        direction: 'column',
        padding: 0,
        items: [
            {
                type: 'listbox',
                name: 'type',
                label: 'Type',
                value: 'internal',
                values: [
                    {
                        text: 'Internal exercise',
                        value: 'internal',
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'External exercise',
                        value: 'external',
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                type: 'textbox',
                name: 'id',
                label: 'Id',
                value: 'Internal'
            },
        ]
    }],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Insert',
            classes: 'btn primary',
            onclick: 'submit',
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onclick: 'close',
        }
    ],
    onSubmit: function(e) {
    console.log(`type: ${e.data.type}; id: ${e.data.id}`);
    editor.insertContent(`&nbsp;<p>Type: ${e.data.type}</p>`);
    editor.insertContent(`&nbsp;<p>Id: ${e.data.id}</p>`);
    }
});
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/anayarojo/pen/RdXozJ?editors=0010